# Rewrite invisible with Apache .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm a newbie in writing .htaccess file and even after 3 hours of tutorial, I still can't achieve what I want...

Hope you could help me :) ! :

**FIRST** I need to redirect my website http://www.runnincity.com to http://www.runnincity.world

To do so, I wrote a .htaccess file located to the root of runnincity.com with the code :

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.runnincity.world/
```

This is fine.

**THEN** I need http://www.runnincity.com/blog to be reachable through the URL http://www.runnincity.world/blog but I don't want the rewriting to be visible for the user. So if the user write http://www.runnincity.world/blog, the URL must stay as it is but display the content of www.runnincity.com/blog .

I wrote a new .htaccess located in the root of runnincity.world with the code below (but doesn't work) :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^runnincity.world/blog$ runnincity.com/blog [P]
```

I feel completely lost ... thanks for your help !

Comment: This needs more information. Is runnincity.com running on a different server than runnincity.world? How are the sites set up? Where do the domain names point?

Comment: Yes they are on two different mutualized hosting server ! What extra info can I give you ? Thanks !

Comment: You would need to use proxying for this, see e.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension